# Unhandled Rejection (typeError): Cannot read property of undefined using reactjs axios on google chrome mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile, axios, typeerror

When inputting incorrect information in my google chrome browser in my laptop I get the error response
here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvqWm.png) of the response in my laptop browser using this code

```
axios
        .post(`${strapi}/auth/local`, loginData)
        .then(res => {
          if (undefined === res.data.jwt) {
            this.setState({error: res.data.message, Loading: false});
            return;
          }

          sessionStorage.setItem('JWT', res.data.jwt);
          sessionStorage.setItem('username', res.data.user.username);
          sessionStorage.setItem('role', res.data.user.role.type);


          this.setState({Loading: false, token: res.data.jwt, username: res.data.user.username, userEmail: res.data.user.email, isLoggedIn: true});
          // window.location.href = '/';
        })
        .catch(err => {
          this.setState({
            error:err.response.data.message[0].messages[0].message
          })
          console.log(this.state.error)
        })
```

however when logging in to my mobile chrome browser using the same lline of code this appears
[mobile screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZfwD.jpg)

how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of error occur when you are not getting your error.response.

So, what you can do is you can set default message if you get any unknown errors.

```
     let MESSAGE;

     if(error.response){
         MESSAGE = err.response.data.message[0].messages[0].message
     }else{
          MESSAGE = 'Something went wrong.'
     }

     this.setState({
         error: MESSAGE
      })
```

Or else you can log your error why this happen

```
 console.log('error',error)
```

Comment: thank you it works but why does it not work on mobile chrome? even putting correct credentials the "Something went wrong" still goes in the state, can you explain why this happens

Comment: .catch(err => console.log(err))    just put only console.log  in your catch

Comment: im planning on using that error response for incorrect credentials

Comment: you can use it but if you are getting error responses from backend then you need to use that as per my suggestion.

Comment: let me know if you are having any problems

Comment: I guess I'll find a way around for the incorrect credentials. Thank you for helping I appreciate it